# Website Not Updating Scripts

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2

The website that I am hosting a website on my Raspberry Pi using Apache2 doesn't seem to update it's scripts when I upload them SFTP.  All of the files are like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the error, I used chown to give the permissions to the website's root folder but I should have used usermod.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors, that should tell you everything you need to know.

Check that the user you're logging in as has write permissions to that directory.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors.

Comment: What SFTP client are you using? Do you have write permissions to that directory? What is the timestamp of the file when you overwrite it? If you can write to /home/username/ but not /var/www/html (or wherever your apache root directory is) then you don't have write permissions. Try setting the root directory for 777 and see if that makes a difference (don't keep it like that, just diagnose the problem and change it back)

Comment: I can write to it and I know for a fact it is there, but the website just doesn't update it.  Also, I use WinSCP for the SFTP.

Comment: Check what your root directory is set to in apache, and that it is the same directory you're writing to. What type of scripts are these? PHP,JS? What do you mean by the website doesn't update it? You don't see the changes you made when you uploaded the file? Create a new file, a test.html or something and check that you can access it when you upload it.